# What hex code do .java files start with?

Tags: java, hex, magic-numbers, hex-editors

I'm trying to get the "magic number" (the bytes that say what format the file is)... I did try to open the file myself in a hex editor. But I only get "70 75" at the start. And that's wrong. I'm doing homework and can't find the right hex code. I do not have much experience with hex editors.

Comment: `.java` files are simple text files. You may want to check `.class` files instead and you will find two words.

Comment: If you mean the `.class` file it should be `0xCAFEBABE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.java` files are the source files. They're plain text files and don't have any particular magic number. `70 75` are the bytes of the characters `pu` - you were probably looking at a `public class ...` definition.

Compiled Java `.class` files start with the bytes `CA FE BA BE` ("Café babe"). See [Java Virtual Machine Specification §4.1 – The ClassFile Structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1)  for a description of the format.

Comment: How do I compile the file exactly? Haven't learned that stuff yet, I'm 3 weeks in on my first semester. We have only experimented with a program called BlueJ, for learning object-oriented Java code..

Comment: Is it just to type, javac fileName.java at the top of the code?

Comment: @minteks Not at the top of the code, [on the command line](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html). BlueJ doubtless compiles your code too, but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know where it puts the compiled files.